# Using a newly created 3D printed object on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, writing-printing, contemporary-halacha, makeh-befatish

If a 3D printer automatically started a new job on Shabbos or was already printing when Shabbos started and the print job finishes on Shabbos, may one peel off the object from the hot bed on Shabbos and use it, or is there an Issur of Nolad, Makeh B'Patish or borderline Zilzul Shabbos?

For example, ice tongs finished printing on Shabbos. Can you use them to grab ice with?

Is there any difference in Halacha if it finished printing during Bein Hashmashos?

In a similar vein, can you read/use a letter that was faxed to you, or printed automatically during Shabbos?

Comment: "borderline Zilzul Shabbos" Borderline??

Comment: What does “peeling the object from the hot bed” mean? Is it actually attached? Does your interaction alter the state of the heat on the bed? This question would require a qualified posek who is familiar with your specific 3D printer and how it functions. I have seen 3D printers where the completed object is not attached to anything, but loose in some kind of media.

Comment: If it’s not considered gomro bdei adam, it would be muktzah, much like wet clothes that dry on shabbos.

Comment: @YaacovDeane, the plastic is semi-attached to a glass bed (or metal), and with a little force, can be cracked clean.